# HTML meta viewport initial scale is no more working?

Tags: html, meta-tags

For a website (angular) that will only be used on desktop, I would like to set the page to load with a default scaling of 90%.

I've searched Google, but none of the examples worked, even though I tried to set the property "initial-scale"="0.9".

What i tried:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9" />
```

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9, user-scalable=no">
```

```
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.9, user-scalable=yes, maximum-scale=5.0″ />
```

But unfortunately none of them work. Is this even supported in browsers anymore? (Chrome, Brave, Firefox)
Or what other solutions are there to set the default scale (CTRL + scroll ) for an HTML page to 90%?

Comment: Your third attempt has invalid quotes for HTML, other than that, these look valid.

Comment: note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meta viewport` was introduced with the early generations of smart phones so they could handle websites designed solely for the screen sizes found on typical computers (which was almost all websites at the time).

By default smart phones would fake having a much larger display then they really had, zoom out by default, and allow the user to zoom and pan.

`meta viewport` allowed a website to declare that it *had* been designed with smart phones in mind (e.g. used media queries) so that the mobile browser could tell that such zooming and panning wasn't needed.

---

The **only** mainstream browsers to **ever** support `meta viewport` are those running on mobile devices.

You shouldn't expect desktop browsers to pay it any attention at all.

---

Setting `initial-scale` to values other than `1` is only there to compensate for CSS not properly designed for mobile devices in the first place.

Just write CSS to express the design you want in the first place (making sure to give consideration to the fact that people do need to be able to read the text at whatever font size it ends up at, and many people will not have eyesight or a screen as good as yours.)

Comment: Smartphones do not fake having a larger display. It is the other way around. Those devices have actually a larger display (physical pixels). A default font-size of 16px would be unreadable and small there. They have a physical high-density screen to allow shaped rounding. What they actually do with the DPR is, to lower the amount of software pixels compared to physical pixels. A DPR of 2 means that 1 software pixel for CSS will actually address 4 physically existing pixels.

Comment: @tacoshy — I was measuring the display size in inches, not pixels.